# What is the best way to connect two numbers via Twilio, and how to get the pricing for the call before hand?

Tags: twilio

I'm trying to establish the recommended way to connect two numbers via Twilio and get the pricing of that call before hand.

The scenario is that a user on my system will call one of his/her contacts. The user's own number is predefined before hand, and they are using a specific sub account.

The way I'm doing it now, is to first call the user's phone, then use a `Dial` verb to call the target. That way, the user answers first, is announced that we're calling "Contact X" and the contact's phone rings. This avoids a lag which would occur on the contact's phone if I called them first. Is there a better way to do it?

As well, I'd like to establish the cost of the call before hand (the cost per minute). I can use the pricing client to get a cost for specific countries, but how do I determine the SOURCE country? The user might be in the UK or the Middle East, calling a contact in the US. The pricing API lets me see the cost to the UK or US but how does the API call knows which country we're calling from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

The way you are setting up the call seems fine to me.

As for the cost of the call, you are actually making two outbound calls in this situation, so the costs are that of an outbound call to each country that you are calling to. In the case of a user in the UK that initiates a call in the way you describe to the US, your cost will be an outbound call to the UK and an outbound call to the US.

There is one different way you could set up the call. If you make your system aware that the next call to a number will be forwarded onto the user you want to call, then your user can make an inbound call to the number and you can return TwiML to forward onto the call recipient. That way you would pay for an inbound call leg from the country the user was calling from (the UK, in the example) and an outbound call in the country the user called to (the US in the example).

Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: so both calls originate from the US, one is to the UK and one to the US, correct? In which case the call is billed as a local US call, and a international US->UK call. 
I rather connect the callers by ringing their phones, instead of having the originator have to dial a number. So I think I'll stick to this strategy. Just needed to figure out the cost.

Comment: There actually isn't the concept of an "international call" from Twilio's perspective. Because we deal with operators all over the world, the cost of a call from Twilio to a country is our local call cost. You can see the charges for a call to the UK on this page: https://www.twilio.com/voice/pricing/gb (or look them up in the pricing API).

Comment: Ok, that's fine. So i can get the total cost of the call by checking hte cost to both participants and adding it up.

Comment: That's exactly right. You can also get the final cost of the call by providing the `<Dial>` verb with an action URL to callback to once the call is over.

Comment: Yes I already have final values. I wanted to present costs before the call takes place. 
Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Would anyone be able to post some TwiML to show how this is done?

Comment: Hi Marcus, the TwiML for this would be a [`<Dial>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/dial), the difference is in how the inbound call is handled. If you have a question related to your own application, it's best to start a new question on SO. If you tag it Twilio then I'll likely find it and try to help :)